# Plotting with matplotlib/cartopy: Program hangs no error message

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have written a program to show my cycling routes from Strava.
I used Python 3.8.2, matplotlib 3.3.3 and cartopy 0.20.1 for that.
After I upgraded matplotlib to 3.5.0 some functions don't work anymore.
I've tried to isolate the problem and wrote a simple piece of code where it seems the problem is with pcolormesh().

In my situation the plot takes place, but the program hangs when I move the mouse over the plot or over the toolbar. I don't see any errors.

The environment that works: OS: Windows 10 Python 3.8.12 Matplotlib: 3.3.3 Cartopy: 0.20.1
The envionment that fails: OS: Windows 10 Python 3.8.12 Matplotlib: 3.5.0 Cartopy: 0.20.1

I created a new virtual environment with:
conda create --name Test python=3.8.12
conda activate Test
conda install matplotlib
conda install cartopy
conda install pandas

With matplotlib 3.3.3 I can increase nx,ny to 8000,6000 without problems.
With matplotlib 3.5.0 everything works fine when I reduce nx, ny to  100,75 in my case. I use it in my program with size (400,300)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(num="TestXX", figsize=(30/2.54, 25/2.54))

#add a map of the Netherlands
request = cimgt.OSM()
ax1=plt.axes(projection=request.crs)
ax1.set_extent([3.25, 7.35, 50.45, 53.55],ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.add_image(request, 10)

#create a rectangular grid a little smaller than the map
#with cell sizes of 0.01 degree filled with random values
nx=400
ny=300
xedges=np.linspace(3.3, 7.3, nx)
yedges=np.linspace(50.5, 53.5, ny)
zvalues=np.random.random((nx, ny))

ax1.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, zvalues.T ,\
               alpha=0.3, shading='auto', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
plt.show()
```

Comment: 3.5.0 is less than a month old so it's possible this is a live bug. This is a really nice [mre] - great job! You could post this on the [matplotlib issues](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) list. See possibly related: [#21846](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21846). If you can, include the commands you're using to set up your environments too, and see if plotting *anything* is possible on 3.5.0 (the linked issue used `plot.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])` or if the issue is specific to pcolormesh or your code. Thanks!

Comment: Note the resolution of that issue I linked to overlapped installs of matplotlib between the base and conda env. I haven't had a chance to text this myself but is it possible that's part of the issue?

Comment: Thanx for your response/advise. I created  a complete new environment with minimal content(see my editted text above) and  add the site_packages. Same result. Plotting is possible when I reduce the amount of xedges, yedges. Can there be a memory problem?

Comment: Did you activate the test env before installing the packages? Otherwise those went into your base env. If so please include the exact steps to reproduce. You're getting into the gnarly deep end of debugging conda envs so people get particular :)

Comment: I did. Added it to the text above. Thnx for the tip!